# Qual a utilidade do vetor ".Random.seed"?

Tags: r

Percebi que no `r` há um vetor oculto no `globalenv()`, chamado `.Random.seed`. Mesmo com o `globalenv()` sem nenhum objeto, `.Random.seed` ainda fica disponível quando se usa a função `ls` com o parâmetro `TRUE` no argumento `all`:

```
ls(all=FALSE)
#character(0)

ls(all=TRUE)
[1] ".Random.seed"
```

E, ao tentar eliminá-lo:

```
rm(list=ls())
```

ele ainda fica disponível, pois o `length` do `globalenv()` tem `1` como resultado:

```
length(globalenv())
[1] 1
```

Assim,

- qual a utilidade do vetor `.Random.seed`?
- como eliminar este vetor? E, quais implicações podem ocorrer caso seja removido?

Comment: Que brisa. Boa pergunta!

Comment: Mas é possível eliminar sim. Basta `rm(list = ls(all.names = TRUE))`. Depois disso, `ls(all.names = TRUE)` resulta em `character(0)`.

Comment: Outra questão interessante é saber por que ele está no `.GlobalEnv`. Outros objetos escondidos, como o `.Library` ficam no `base`, por exemplo.

Comment: Editei a pegunta com base no seu comentário.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

.Random.seed é um vetor de inteiros, contendo o estado do gerador de números aleatórios (RNG) para a geração de números aleatórios em R. Ele pode ser salvo e restaurado, mas não deve ser alterado pelo usuário.

Ele é aplicado em funções como `rnorm`, `rexp`, ..., que geram números aleatórios em determinadas distribuições. Então se você não estiver usando números aleatórios, então não deverá ter problemas.

Answer (score 1):

Vou complementar a resposta dada pelo @Márcio Mocellin, referente ao segundo tópico:

> como eliminar este objeto?

Como citado pelo @Tomás Barcellos nos comentários:

```
rm(list = ls(all.names = TRUE))
ls(all.names = TRUE)
```

> E, quais implicações podem ocorrer caso seja removido?

Fiz dois testes para verificar a existência de possíveis problemas quanto a isso:

- primeiro, eliminei `.Random.seed`;
- segundo, apliquei duas funções que geram e definem padrões de números aleatórios (apliquei `sample` e `set.seed`, respectivamente).

`sample` funcionou corretamente. E, curiosamente, `.Random.seed` foi ativada, retornando ao `globalenv()`. Para provar isto:

```
#Eliminar .Random.seed do globalenv()
rm(list = ls(all.names = TRUE))
ls(all.names = TRUE)
#character(0)

#Aplicação da função
x<-sample(1:10,10,replace=T)
#[1] 44 39 27 17 10 17 49 49  5 21

#Reaparecimento da função .Random.seed ao globalenv()
ls(all.names = TRUE)
#[1] ".Random.seed" "x"
```

Quando usa-se a função `set.seed`, `.Random.seed` também é ativada e retorna ao `globalenv()`:

```
#Eliminar .Random.seed do globalenv()
rm(list = ls(all.names = TRUE))
ls(all.names = TRUE)
#character(0)

#Aplicação da função
set.seed(456)

#Reaparecimento da função .Random.seed ao globalenv()
ls(all.names = TRUE)
[1] ".Random.seed"
```

- *Esta foi uma resposta empírica, baseada em testes*. Não sei dizer se existe alguma situação na qual a remoção de `.Random.seed` seja prejudicial. Só a teoria pode dizer isto. Infelizmente, não encontrei nada (confiável) sobre.